# How to output "<" and ">" symbols to a text file using batch script

Tags: html, batch-file, scripting

I created a simple batch script to format some HTML codes that i use on a regular basis.  My current workaround is outputting 888 and 999 and going back into the text file and replacing all 888's with a < and all 999's with a >.  I know batch uses these symbols and redirects so i wanted to know if there was a way to bypass this. Below is an example.

```
888div id="bestlinkstop"999
    888a href=" " target="_blank"999 888img src=" "999 888/a999
888/div999
```

changing all 8's and 9's to < and >

```
<div id="bestlinkstop">
    <a href=" " target="_blank"> <img src=" "> </a>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will have a much more enjoyable time if switching to PowerShell. Batch (cmd.exe) parsing rules are .. terrible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Windows escape character is `^` to escape the brackets.

Something like

```
echo mystring ^< div id="bestlinkstop" ^> something >>myfile.txt
```